# Why does my player health not change when I want it to

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, variables

In my game I have a player with health and I am currently trying to add a healthbar but my one problem is that when my player loses hp my healthbar doesn't change. In my scripts the script that updates the heathbar is linked to my health script but when my player loses hp, the players hp doesn't change in the healthbar and I am unsure why. I know that the player does lose hp so the problem is that even though the scripts are linked the hp doesn't change on the separate script. The script for my healthbar:

Apologies if the code is bad I am a noob programmer.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HealthBArScript : Health
{   

    private void Update()
    {     
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(healthPoints / 100, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

}
```

The script for my health if that is necessary:

```
     using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class Health : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public float healthPoints = 100.0f; 
    private Coroutine onHit = null;

    private void Update()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Updaate());      
    }

    IEnumerator Updaate()
    {       
        if (healthPoints <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        if (healthPoints >= 101.0f)
        {
            healthPoints = 100.0f;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
    }
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Zombie")
        {
            if (onHit == null)
                onHit = StartCoroutine(HitDelay());
        }

        if(coll.gameObject.tag == "Health")
        {
            healthPoints = healthPoints + 10; 
        }

        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Health_1")
        {
            healthPoints = 100.0f;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator HitDelay()
    {
        healthPoints = healthPoints - 25;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
        onHit = null;
    }   

}
```

Comment: So the health bar script is on the health bar?  How does the health bar know about the health of your player?  I think maybe you are confusing inheritance  and references.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I believe it is inheritance but I am not sure. I can't remember what exactly it is but the best way I can explain it is that instead of `MonoBehaviour` I use `Health`. I think that is inheritence but I am not sure

Comment: Yes, that part is inheritance.  Please correct me if i am wrong.  I assume you have the HealthBarScript on a UI element of some sort.  You then have the Health script on your player object.  Is this correct?

Comment: @hijinxbassist Yes that is correct

Comment: Ok. So you are indeed confusing Inheritance and references.  A reference refers to a specific instance of something, ie. Health.  There can be any number of Health scripts in the scene, you need to reference the one on the player object.  Let me make a quick example, 1 min.

Comment: Please do not tag your question as `visual-studio` unless you are actually experiencing a problem with VS or your situation is somehow unique to VS. Just because you're using VS as your IDE doesn't mean the issue has anything to do with VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is NOT have your health bar inherit the Health script.  Inheritance will allow you to extend the class, that is not what you want to do here.  Instead you want a reference to an instance of the Health class from your health bar script.

Put the health on the game object that needs health. player, enemy, etc.

```
public class Health : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The actual health value
    //
    public float healthPoints;
}
```

And put the healthbar on your UI element:

```
public class HealthBar : MonoBehaviour
{
    // A reference to the Health we want to display
    //
    public Health trackedHealth;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(trackedHealth.healthPoints / 100, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

From the inspector you will drag the object with the health script attached onto the trackedHealth variable of the healthbar script.  It now has a reference to the health it will display.

Scaling the transform in Update will suffice for now, but consider moving away from update for these infrequent changes.  For quick tests and learning, this is perfectly fine though.

Comment: Thank you it worked. I was working on this for ages

Comment: No problem, glad i was able to help.  Keep at it, its a tough road up, but a great ride down

Answer (score 2):

Let me tell you some basic things regarding unity programming and why a couple of things that do not make much sense.

1.- Monobehaviour class is the class you need to inherit from when you need to handle same gameobject behaviour in the scene. This can be attahched to the gameObjects in the editor to program the commont behaviour of the gameobjects, like position, rotation etc. That is why that class holds the methods for this, `Start()`, `Update()` etc.

2.- Inheritance makes that your class type hold all the features of the parent (the class you inherit from) and the new ones you add in your child class. Unless you need a class that uses some or all of the methods/properties of `Health`, you dont need to inherit from it. So `public class HealthBArScript : Health` does not make much sense. To inherit means to hold all the parent features plus some specialized new ones.

Check any simple inheritance [example](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_inheritance.asp) to get the point.

3.- `Update()` is called once every frame, so approx 60 times per second. That is why, setting the scale all the time again and again, in the update:

```
private void Update()
{     
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(healthPoints / 100, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Does not make much sense. You can set that in the editor, in the Transform component, or in the `Start()` method of the corresponding Monobehaviour component in case you might need some logic.

4.- Regarding coroutines, you do not need coroutines for what you are doing. You can read the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html).
Also you are starting a corroutine in the `Update()`

```
private void Update()
{
    StartCoroutine(Updaate());      
}
```

Which will probably crash your game or something unexpected. I would start to handle my code as simple as possible in the `Update()` and in the monoheviour methods, and when the need comes along you can explore the use of coroutines, as they must be used with care.

Finally:

You player and your healbar seem that need to be two diferent classes that inherit from Monobehaviour. Its easy because gameobjects of different kind usually need their spare monobehaviour inherited class while things stay simple. Then you need to comunicate those two classes so that when the player looses hp, you your healbar decreases the amount in some display. Sure that with any small tutorial you are able to get to that point.